# Automating Jira Cloud backup

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, python-jira

Is there a way to automate backups for my Jira Cloud site on a daily basis including pulling all the data and attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlassian provides option to import-export xml however that cannot be automated as far as I know. Your next best bet to automate it by yourself would be Jira developer APIs (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/).

Using APIs you can pull data to a greater extent. However it may not be as intuitive as you may want or how it used to be on the on-prem version of Jira server (DB backups). However you may want to plan the efforts & cost for the script maintenance, cataloging the downloaded data and maintaining the data for long term. You can find some details in this thread - [JIRA with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209485/jira-with-python)

Alternatively you may want to go for 3rd party apps in Atlassian marketplace which supports automatic/scheduled backups of Issues & Configuration, granular & full project restores, long term storage and secure offsite storage.

Disclaimer - I work at Revyz, we have developed a Jira app which solves this exact problem. We backup & restore Atlassian Jira along with other features as mentioned above. You may want to take a look at https://www.revyz.io/ &
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1228694/revyz-backup-restore?hosting=cloud&tab=overview

Comment: After evaluating multiple Jira Cloud backup tools, I have created an article on substack which lists out my findings - https://anjabcalhoun.substack.com/p/3-best-jira-cloud-backup-providers